# Filter by field with array value in ACF on WP REST API

Tags: php, filters, array, rest-api

I'm suffering for weeks trying make a `GET` call in the `WP REST API` where I have a field in the `ACF` plug-in with multiple select, and the stored value is an `array()`.

Example of the response after the call in `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

```
{
        ...
        },
        ...
        "acf": {
            ...
            "ddd": [
                "11",
                "12",
                "13",
                "14"
            ],
            ...
        ...
}
```

And the response when I call in `/wp-json/acf/v3/posts`

```
[
    {
        ...
        "acf": {
        ...
        "ddd": [
                "11",
                "12",
                "13",
                "14"
            ],
        ...
      }
   }
]
```

So, the problem is when I use this function in `functions.php` of my theme:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', function( $args ) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'ddd',
            'value' => esc_sql( $_GET['ddd'] ),

        )
    );

    return $args;

} );
```

I'm able to filter like this: `/wp-json/acf/v3/posts?fieldname=value` and I perfect give the posts filtered by the terms in the URL, but this works for simple fields. In my specific need the field `ddd` is an array, because in the ACF I'm working with a multiple selection field. So when I try to filter using the function above I just get a empty response: `[]`.

I've tried too to use the `Tags` field from `WordPress Core`, what is a `array` value in `REST` response too, but I never managed to make it work, even using the deprecated function `filter[key]=&filter[value]=` from `WordPress`.

Useful informations:

> 1. I try to get support with the `ACF` devs, no help is provided about it;
> 2. I use the `ACF to REST API` plug-in to expose the ACF fields to the REST API and the dev is trying to help my with this case;
> 3. My WordPress is 4.9.2 and PHP are 7.1.12 version.

I don't necessarily need to just go the way of filtering the call using the URL, it might be a different logic to do this in PHP with some pre-loop to be able to filter only posts with some field values like conditions, eg age, region, sex ... because they will be multiple filters at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Advanced Custom Fields stores values for multiple select fields as a serialised Array. For a select field with options 'one' and 'three' selected, the value stored on the database would look like this:

```
'a:2:{i:0;s:3:"one";i:1;s:5:"three";}'
```

It is simply not possible with `WP_Query` (which is where your meta query ends up) or SQL to filter results based on selected values stored this way. MySQL sees this value as a generic string, and cannot understand that there are distinct values contained in it ('one' or 'three', let alone query based on them. This is because serialisation occurs entirely in PHP and MySQL doesn't know about it. It's the same as if you stored JSON in a MySQL column: MySQL wouldn't know anything about the data structure. It's just text.

You either need to replace ACF with a solution that lets you store data the way you want (a custom taxonomy would be the simplest option), or use ACF's APIs & filters to change the way it stores data. You will need to refer to ACF resources and documentation to figure out how to do this, as it would be off-topic here (this question, as asked, is off-topic too, but I'm treating it as a question about `meta_query` and serialised data).

Comment: Finally found a straight answer to this, thank you, @jacob-peattie. Is it possible to filter by ACF custom field value in this case? `"acf": { "enhanced_listing": false, "enhanced_listing_picture": "1.jpg" }` I want to filter only enhanced listings with the value of true

Comment: You would need to ask the developers of ACF.